# How to create a Screen in flutter where I can insert text and insert pictures as well in random order (Like MS word)?

Tags: image, flutter, textfield, alternate

I want my screen to be exactly like quora mobile app's answer creating page/ like MS word where we can add text and images in any order as we want. The only way I could come up with is to create a TextField() inside a column widget and create a Image() widget when user tries to add a Image and add another TextField() widget after that to continue writing after the image. The problem here is that, since these three are different widgets, a user cannot copy/change text from first and third TextFields (not second because second widget is an Image) simultaneously. Is there anything that can be done about it?

[Here is an image reference of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edh3V.jpg)

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented apps by using [zefyr](https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr) package. It required some minor customisations, nevertheless it works well.

See an example screenshot of my app which is using this package.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! will check it out.

Comment: you are welcome. If the answer is helpful please remember to accept and vote it. see guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers